# Simple question about deleting an object from a Ruby array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have a Ruby (1.9.2) array which I need to remove an object from.

```
[object1, object2, object3]
```

At the moment I'm doing

```
array.delete_at(1)
```

which removes the object, but then there is an empty array spot at that index.

```
[object1, , object3]
```

How do I remove an object so that the array is resized so that there is no empty spot in the array?

```
[object1, object3]
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: For future reference, if you have an array with nil elements, you can use `Array.compact` to strip them out.

Comment: Not sure why your question got downvoted, but I did a +1 to it because it's a valid question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
irb> a = [1,2,3]
=> [1, 2, 3]
irb> a.delete_at 1
=> 2
irb> a
=> [1, 3]
```

No spots here...

Comment: Confirmed, with 1.8.7, 1.9.1, and 1.9.2

Answer (score 0):

I think slice! is the method you're looking for

```
>> arr = [object1, object2, object3]
[object1, object2, object3]

>> arr.slice!(1)
object2

>> arr
[object1, object3]
```